# How do I modify movement speed while attacking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I hate all that "skittering" during combat?

I'm looking for a way to modify movements speed while attacking or casting, similar to the way mods like Deadly Combat do. I would like to make characters still if casting or attacking.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

I'm fine with creation kit btw. I've made a few simple mods for myself!

Comment: I think this should be on gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @kotekzot Depends how much work is needed. I see more then a view console or other advanced answers for questions. And then there might be mods that can help him out, no need to reinvent the wheel. If he posts this on gamedev i doubt he gets much views. However a skyrim moding community would be much better for these kind of questions.

Comment: I don't find your question that clear. Do you wish to make your own char stand still, or anyone else? Considering that moving during casting spells, having a bow drawn or attacking, is a part of making the combat dynamic in the game. My guess for a 'fix', would be to use a mod. But if you only want that particular thing, and not everything else the mod offers, use CK with the mod as active file, and see if you can remove everything else, even though that will most likely violate the terms of use.

Comment: The first sentence being a question made me laugh out loud.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to accomplish this is to modify the `speedmult` av during an attack/cast animation. The best, and perhaps only, way to do that is through modding. There are no mods currently available for Skyrim for this purpose, so you're going to have to figure it out for yourself.

Keep in mind, if you set `speedmult` to 0 when attacking, you may eliminate the ability to perform charging attacks.

If you need assistance determining how to achieve something like this through modding, I recommend asking around one of the Skyrim modding communities, [Nexus](http://www.nexusmods.com) being one of the most active and well-respected.

Answer (score 0):

In archery I picked the perk causing enemies to move slower while aiming. With melee I use built up stamina to do power attacks in which are shown in slow motion. Not sure if that's the answer your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Ice damage and slow potions can reduce enemy speed, making you faster in comparison

---

An alternative answer to get a speed advantage on your enemies is to use the "Slow" poison on them. This will reduce their movement speed by 50%

If you need it, here is a list of the ingredients that can be used:

- Burnt Spriggan Wood
- Deathbell
- Large Antlers
- Poison Bloom
- River Betty
- Salt Pile
- Trama Root

---

An alternative to slow is ice damage. You can either use ice spells or a weapon enchanted with ice damage.

Here is a list of possible ice spells you can use

- Frost Cloak
- Frost Rune
- Frostbite
- Icy Spear
- Ice Spike

---

Sources: Personal experience and these wiki pages: [Slow Potion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Slow), [Ice Damage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Frost_Damage)

Answer (score 0):

There's a console command/cheat that can change the attack speed of your character. If you press ` it will open the console, then type in 'player.setav weaponspeedmult 2'. 1 is normal speed.